# Array - Last index

Tags: c++, arrays

In an array, the index of the first element is zero. So an array declared as:

```
int a[5];
```

should have a[4] as the last element. However, when I execute the following code:

```
int n;
cin>>n;
int a[n];
for(int i = 0; i++<n; cin>>a[i]);
for(int i = 0; i++<n; cout<<i<<" "<<a[i]<<endl);
```

And give the input as:

```
5 1 2 3 4 5
```

The output is:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
```

That implies that a[5] = 5. I was wondering as to how that is possible. Shouldn't it display some garbage value instead?

Comment: The first input is the array size. Then the array elements are given

Comment: Yes, so, a[0] = 1, a[1] = 2 and so on until a[4] = 5. But the above output implies, when i = 5, a[i] = 5.

Comment: I do not understand the reason behind the downvotes for the question. This is a sincere question, coming from a beginner.

Comment: ***int a[n];*** Is not legal c++. I would avoid VLAs and use c++ instead. Although I suspect your class prohibits you from using the standard library at this point..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logical. You are doing it wrong. Consider corner where `n = 5`:

Your `i` is `4`. You do check if `i++ < 5` is true and after check, i increases.
I is now `5` and this is out of bounds.

Your loop actually runs from 1 to 5 instead of 0 to 4.

Rewrite codes to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; cin >> a[i], i++);
for (int i = 0; i < n; cout << i << " " << a[i] << endl, i++);
```

Comment: Yes, exactly. So why does it give that a[5] = 5 even though a[5] is out of bounds? Shouldn't it result in some garbage value?

Comment: C++ does not control you what you are doing. You were just lucky that it worked, but it was *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Why not write it the normal way, seperating control and code? I'd see this as much more readable `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) cin >> a[i];`

Comment: @HeroicKatora Nobody can read that :P Even better: `std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin), 5, std::begin(a));` :)

Answer (score 3):

change `i++ < n` to `i < n` and `cin>>a[i]` to `cin>>a[i++]`

Comment: Wrong! First index is still ignored!

Comment: it doesn,t now. thanks for your comment.I've forgotten sth

Answer (score 0):

> Shouldn't it display some garbage value instead?

Teaching that an unitialized variable has a garbage value or that accessing an array will yield garbage values is really a disservice.

Accessing an uninitialized variable or an array out of bounds in C++ is **Undefined Behavior**. This means that the program can behave in **any** way. It can crash, it can appear to function, it can any behavior, it can appear to have garbage values in unitialized variables.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could  just replace 
`int i=0` by `int i=-1`   and, 
`i++` by `++i` 
Now the loop will run and enter the values from a[0] to a[4] as expected.
The code could be rewritten as:

```
for(int i=-1;++i<n;cin>>a[i]);
for(int i=-1;++i<n;cout<<i<<" "<<a[i]<<endl);
```